# use min() and avg () in subquery

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, average, min

I'm working on db2 from ibm cloud and sql.
My data contains 1 table with 3 columns: schools, their overall performance (level) and location.
I want to find the location with the least AVERAGE level using a subquery with avg and min.

I have this code which does the job:

```
select location, avg(level) as avglevel
from schools_table
group by location
order by avglvl
limit 1;
```

But i'm looking for something more like:

```
select location
from schools_table
where level = (select min(level) from schools_table);
```

this yields the minimum of all the values. However i'm interested in the minimum of the average.

please help
Many thanks for any insight.

Arturo

Comment: What do you not like about your code, that uses `order by`  and `limit`?

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  You have two tables mentioned in the question.  The description of the table in the text does not match the columns used in the queries.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry i mixed two tables you are right. I fixed it already, and I think the answer from fahmi is what I was looking for.

Comment: @GMB, you are right, i specially don't like the limit line. Instead of ordering by and limiting to 1 row, I wanted to get the answer with the min() function.

Comment: What if two locations have the same average level and both are equal to the minimum? One of them would be lost if you use `limit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
with cte as
(
select location,avg(safety_score) as safety_score  from chicago_public_schools group by location
)
select community_area_name
from chicago_public_schools
where safety_score = (select min(safety_score) from cte)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that's it. I'm a beginner with sql and I didn't know about the with statement. Just for curiosity, could it be possible without it? Like, somehow, generate that variable/new table cte in a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need

```
select community_area_name
from chicago_public_schools
where safety_score = (select avg(safety_score)
                      from chicago_public_schools 
                      group by location
                      order by avg(safety_score) asc --sort the result
                      limit 1); --pick the smallest avg
```

Now.. I don't recommend this for performance reason, but if you really really want to to avoid `order by` with `limit` and also don't want to use a `cte`, you could use a `window function`

```
select community_area_name
from chicago_public_schools
where safety_score = (select distinct min(avg(safety_score)) over()
                      from chicago_public_schools 
                      group by location)
```

And if you want to avoid `window functions` too, you could rely solely on subqueries, but then-- it's too ugly

```
select community_area_name
from chicago_public_schools a
join (select min(safety_score) as min_safety_score
      from (select avg(safety_score) as safety_score  
            from chicago_public_schools 
            group by location) b) c on a.safety_score = c.min_safety_score
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I was looking for a code that gets the lowest average with the min() function. Your way is very similar to the one I have in the question. However, you manage to make it in a subquery which I also find interesting. Thanks again!

Comment: @arturo451 No problem, I added in another alternative for learning sake